# Pass object of custom class as parameter to another class

Tags: class, sobject, parameters, inner-class

I want to make something like in the code below, but it didnt work. Erorr: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void method1() from the type SObject.

```
public with sharing class Test1{
    public  class InnerTest1{ 
        public String method1()
    }    
}

public with sharing class Test3{
    public String method1(sObject innerTest1Obj)
    InnerTest1.method1()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test1.InnerTest1 is not an sObject, or a child of sObject, so you can't treat it as such.

You'd write:

```
public with sharing class Test1{
  public class InnerTest1 { 
    public String method1() {
    }    
  }
}

public with sharing class Test3{
  public String method1(Test1.InnerTest1 innerTest1Obj) {
    InnerTest1.method1();
  }
}
```

In order to use `method1()` from `Test1.InnerTest1`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try.